# Connection's MAC address randomly changes on Windows 10, then stops

Tags: sql-server-2016, connections, network, windows-10

Because reasons (tm), [we want to identify the client's MAC address](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) on SQL Server side (local network, not about security, enables a very convenient feature in way transparent for applications).
We do that by querying `net_address` from `master.dbo.sysprocesses`. All clients are set up to use TCP/IP connections, the address value has always been correct, and all connections from the same computer have always had the same `net_address`.

In Windows 10 clients, however, every single connection gets its own `net_address`, and they do not repeat. The only pattern we can see about these addresses is that the last two digits remain the same within approximately 6 seconds. So if another connection gets assigned with `EBC1E384F4C2`, all subsequent connections' addresses will also end with `C2` until the 6 seconds elapse, then the suffix changes for another 6 seconds.

We have tried in various combinations:

- running cliconfg.exe and making sure only TCP/IP is enabled, and that there is an alias for the server name that is also set to use TCP/IP
- disabling and enabling back connection pooling in the ODBC Data Sources
- adding and removing [`Network Library=DBMSSOCN` or `Network=DBMSSOCN`](https://www.connectionstrings.com/define-sql-server-network-protocol/) to and from the connection properties, depending on the connection type
- setting and removing a fixed MAC address in the network adapter properties
- removing and adding back TCP/IP v6 support from and to the network connection properties
- reading about [MAC randomization in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027925/windows-how-and-why-to-use-random-hardware-addresses) which claims it only applies to Wi-Fi connections, and we only have wired connections

Nothing seemed to have any effect.

The only thing that did seem to have effect is:

- You **toggle** the connection pooling status in ODBC Data Sources (does not matter if it was on or off, what matters is that you flip the status to the opposite), *but only provided that*
- The system has been running for at least about 12 minutes after startup. If you flip the pooling status earlier than that, it will seemingly not have any effect.

The moment you do that, the addresses stop changing, but they do not revert to the actual MAC address of the network adapter, instead they freeze at whatever values they had when the freeze happened, and from then on each application will receive the same MAC for all its subsequent connections, but that MAC will be different among different application on the same device. If you close and run an application again, it will receive its frozen MAC address again as if you never closed it.

---

What is going on? How do we stop it from happening so that TCP/IP connections properly use the network adapter's MAC as opposed to a random address?

Alternatively, is there a better way to reliably identify and distinguish client devices (not users) on a local network from SQL Server (e.g. `hostname` is no good because it depends on the connection string)?

Comment: Can you see correct client’s MAC address at the OS level? i.e via getmac command? 
Thinking out loud (more of a temporary hack than a proper solution) You could utilise powershell to run “getmac /s IP” via agent job for each connected IP every minute or so or even via xp_cmdshell in a logon trigger. Interesting problem to solve.

Comment: If you're able to force TCP/IP why not just use client_net_address from sys.dm_exec_connections instead of MAC address?

Comment: @MarcinGminski `ipconfig` shows a MAC address for the network adapter. This address does not appear to be changing. In the "Advanced" properties of the adapter, the "Network address" is "Not present". If I switch it to a fixed value and provide a static MAC address (e.g. the one that ipconfig shows), that does not do anything. A powershell or trigger solution would be no good because the very point is that at any moment any stored procedure must be able to look up some additional data for the connection based on its network address (which in this case is a device id). It worked for 15 years.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, that is what we are looking in at the moment. The code was originally written for SQL Server 2000 where there was no `sys.dm_exec_connections`. Can we expect it to be as stable as MAC address was for 15 years? Any known gotchas?

Comment: @GSerg I was more thinking to check that the Windows Server that hosts SQL Server registers correct MACs of incoming connections from Win10 clients. To do this you can either do ARP -a or getmac /s, nothing to do with ipconfig. This would be my first attempt to establish where the root cause could be. Also worth checking what MACs are being registered in DHCP and Gateways to rule out Windows 10 randomising it somehow.

Comment: Can I guarantee that some future version or feature in Windows will not randomize how a client's IP address appears to a server? Or whether this can be used if you change client libraries / drivers or change the set of network protocols enabled for the instance? Or if all clients won't appear the same to the server if you change your network firewall or introduce a proxy or load balancer in the middle? Of course not.

Comment: @AaronBertrand No, I was talking about just the SQL Server portion of it that you might know about in advance. E.g. that `client_net_address` is always null under condition X, or that it may be invalid when the corresponding `master.dbo.sysprocesses.net_address` is valid.

Comment: Well `sysprocesses` is deprecated so I can't imagine it would ever have a valid value while `dm_exec_connections` has something invalid. I suspect the opposite is far, far, far more likely to be true, and that becomes likelier with every new release.

Comment: @MarcinGminski `getmac /s` on the server returns only the correct MAC of the client. `arp -a` also shows only the correct MACs. Executing `getmac /s` from inside the connection via cmdshell only shows the correct MAC. Executing `arp -a` from inside the connection via cmdshell only shows the correct MAC. At no point the values from `net_address` seem to appear anywhere on the system utilities output. `sys.dm_exec_connections.client_net_address` seems to be correct at all times.

Answer (score -1):

One of the things you have if you use IPv6 is something called Privacy Extensions. This changes the IP address every hour (or whatever implementation specific time). This guarantees anonymity of the MAC.

Comment: Like said above, we have tried removing IPv6 support from the adapter. It does not have any effect. The MAC address changes with every request, not every hour. The IP address stays the same.